# Change currency based on user location

Tags: magento-1.7

Just wondering is there an easy way to change currency based on a user location? So if someone from Germany visits the site, prices automatically change to Euros and someone from USA prices automatically change to dollar.

Is this possible in Magento or will we have to use an extension to perform this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There's no integrated feature in Magento 1.x which performs the described action.

The easiest and fastest way to achieve this would be by buying an already  existing extension from a trusted Magento Developer (check ratings & reviews).

Otherwise, you can proceed by developing your own extension, but it might take you a while especially if it's the first time you develop a Magento Extension.

Either way, using an Extension is the correct approach for this scenario and by any means don't edit Magento's CORE files, otherwise you'll regret it later on :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a feature in the basic Magento, but an experienced developer can easily fix this. If you don't know how to do it yourself, the best solution is to buy a module like Currency Auto Switcher (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=Currency+Auto+Switcher&pl=0).

Please contact the support before purchase to understand if the module fully suites your requirements. In case you will choose to write such a module by yourself, we recommend to use GeoIP base from MaxMind. Then you’ll need an observer to download the store where you can monitor users location and change the currency respectively to their demands. Also, you will need a spreadsheet to store Country-Currency Relations. Don’t forget to allow users to switch currencies manually.